# Python xpath - Exclude content with style="display:none"

Tags: python, xpath

I'm using xpath to get some information from a website and I came across a block of code that contains `style="display:none` or `block` and I want to only include the code that has `display:block`; I watched some examples but I couldn't get it working on my code. I want to use an `if` statement to run the code if it has `display:block` but I don't know if that is possible. This is what I have:

```
    if guide_page.xpath(".//div[@class='build-box']/@style/text()") == "display: block;":
        for build_names in guide_page.xpath(".//div[@class='build-gradient']"):
            for title in build_names.xpath("div/h2/text()"):
                print("\n")
                print(title)
```

And this is the `div` that has it:

```
<div class="build-box" style="display: block;">
```

I'm not sure if I should paste more of the html or if that's enough, otherwise, please tell me and thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using `if` statement. Just add a `not(...condition...)` in predicate to exclude elements matching certain condition. For example, the following XPath returns `div` elements with certain `class` attribute value, that don't have attribute `style="display: block;"` :

```
.//div[@class='build-box' and not(@style='display: block;')]
```